# How can I stop my website asking users for their permission to use their facebook details?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

can some one take a look at a site I've been building.. the content is generated from a facebook event page. The problem is it asks the user who comes to the site to share information with my website... But i don't want any info from them.. How do I authenticate the site with Facebook in way that does not as the user for their permission to user the FB details.... www.delete-cardiff.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.....How are you getting the event from facebook? You only need to add this get to your site to get the event. https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx where xxx is the event id.

Comment: Yes but to get the event wall feed I need permissions... Hence why I had to setup the authentication process..

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is the problem, but you are requesting an access token from the user in the getToken function:

```
var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?'
```

so there must be your redirection, i guess...maybe you can get the data without a facebook app?

for example, if you want to get the albums of a facebook page:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/[pageid]/albums');
$albums = json_decode($contents,true);
```

i dunno if it also works that way with the stream of an event page though...